# Can a Mleccha become a Brahmana or Kshatriya or Vaishya or Shudra?

Tags: caste-system, other-religions, varna, bhavishya-purana

Mlecchas are those who live outside Bharata Varsha. As they live outside India, they don't have any Varna and they should be considered as lower than all Varnas. But if a Mleccha convert to Hinduism, considering the story written [here](http://hinduonline.co/Scriptures/Puranas/BhavishyaPurana.html) in Bhavishya Purana, can he become a dvija or a Shudra?

The story written there is:

> Then the sage went to the country known as Misra and put all the mlecchas into illusion by the greace of goddess Sarasvati.
>
> **Then he made 10,000 people as dvijas or twice born brahmanas; he made
>   2,000 people into vaishyas; and the rest of them as shudras.** He came
>   back with them and staying in Arya-desha (India) he engaged in the
>   activites of the sages. They were known as Aryans and by the grace of
>   goddess Sarasvati their generation gradually increased upto 4 million,
>   both the men and women with their sons and grandsons. Their king,
>   Kasyapa muni, ruled the earth for 120 years.

Comment: Yes , varna is not from birth, but by behaviour

Comment: @sysinit Varna is based on birth.

Comment: It seems like you answered your own question. The blockquote should probably go into an answer else this looks like a statement/observation than a real question.

Comment: I second @sv. You answered your question in the paragraph. Add what is your actual question in the body and if you are answering the question, add it is an answer.

Comment: @Parikshita The vedic concept of varna is based on occupation and not on birth. Each Varna has got its dharma or discipline and the people of the varna are supposed to follow their dharma. The concept of birth defining Varna is of recent origin, from the later Guptas in the second half of Sixth Century CE (genetic research has shown that the segregation of castes was enforced then on) and I may humbly submit Sanatana Dharma is definitely more than 1500 years old.

Comment: @ tekkk - if varna is behavior based, behavior is not a constant and changes frequently even with every interaction and situation.  Secondly if it was mere based on behavior why haven’t the better behaved among the outcastes and tribals been promoted into savarna hindu society?  How is it easier for Mlechchas only? And what would be their jati, kula, gothra besides varna..???

Comment: User9554-pl provide citations for the answer you provided